# How to force break \url?

Tags: bibliographies

I want to break the web link shown in figure to not be out of margin

[image]

I am using JabRef software to deal with my references and i wrote this link as follows :

```
\url{http://www.fuelcelltoday.com/news-archive/2012/august/fuel-cell-to-power-equipment-on-board-ocean-rowing-boat-during-world-record-attempt}
```

My used packages are:

```
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[square,compress]{natbib}            
%% \removecolourlinks   
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}         
\usepackage{pgfplots}         
\usepackage{threeparttable}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}        
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{subfigure}        
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\newcommand*{\head}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Try to load `url` package.

Comment: If you can't get the `url` package to do it, you could develop your own method, such as `\newcommand\breakurl[1]{\bgroup\ttfamily\breakrefhelp#1\relax\relax\egroup}
\def\breakrefhelp#1#2\relax{#1\penalty0\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\breakrefhelp#2\relax\fi}`

Comment: Maybe adding `\usepackage{url}
\makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\makeatother` to the preamble will help.